# Remove HTML Tags in C

Tags: c, regex, html-parsing

In my program, i have downloaded a webpage with wget and i want to extract on it, only a text string.

What should i do (if it is right) for clear the html tag from the file for have only the text on the webpage?

I've never used regex in C and i don't know if it is the right way for this trouble.
Can you advise me for other alternatives, or librarys, that i can use? 
Or if i should use the regex can you help me to doing a replace tag like this in C?

```
sed -e 's/<[^>]\+>/ /g' file.html
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Regular expressions aren't suited for parsing HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) As long as you have XHTML, that's guaranteed to be valid XML, so you can use an [XML parser library](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) for parsing it.

Comment: Are there other HTML parsing libraries to be aware of?  I'd like to add them to http://htmlparsing.com/

Comment: @AndyLester [libtidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/), [libhtml](http://libhtml.bsd.lv/), [Hubbub](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/projects/hubbub/), [HTMLCXX](http://htmlcxx.sourceforge.net/), et cetera, et cetera...

Comment: Heh, I forgot about libtidy.  I wrote a Perl wrapper around it: http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Tidy :-)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  I've made an issue based on this question: https://github.com/petdance/htmlparsing/issues/9

Answer (score 0):

The other answer points to the most relevant point, namely you cannot parse HTML with a regex...

This is pointing out that your sed script won't work either...

```
<a href="http://localhost/" title="Click &lt; link >">A link</a>
```

The above is valid XML let alone the fast and loose HTML as the closing `>` is valid unescaped in XML... you only have to escape `&` and `<`... its just best practice to escape `>` as well